Invalid `RNSVG.podspec` file: undefined method `visionos' for #<Pod::Specification name="RNSVG">
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 
[!] Invalid `RNSVG.podspec` file: undefined method `visionos' for #<Pod::Specification name="RNSVG">.

from /Users/apple/repos/vendo/node_modules/react-native-svg/RNSVG.podspec:18
 -------------------------------------------
     s.tvos.exclude_files = '**/*.macos.{h,m,mm}'
 >    s.visionos.exclude_files = '**/*.macos.{h,m,mm}'
     s.osx.exclude_files = '**/*.ios.{h,m,mm}'
   -------------------------------------------
.

   from /Users/apple/repos/vendo/ios/Podfile:18
   -------------------------------------------
   target 'vendo' do
 >    config = use_native_modules!
   
a

after install a new versions of react-native and when I install react-native-svg it give me this error. no other depdencies are installed. it was a fresh project created with npx react-native init
